# how to reset MediaRecorder.setVideoSizewithout stoping recording in a service

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-mediarecorder

how to reset MediaRecorder.setVideoSize without stoping recording  in a service

in android we can manage the orientation of video recording with `MediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation)`, this records the video even when orientation has changed

how ever how can we manage to change the `setVideoSize` when we are recording the video

for example, if previously with a `portrait` orientation, the height and width were set to `960/540` and now when orientation changes to `Landscape` , change the 
height and width to `540/960` , without stopping the recording

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to change video size in such cases, that's why orientation hint is needed here...